# What is the best alternative for enum in Android?

Tags: android, enums

if enum is not a memory friendly type then what is the best alternative for that in the Android environment.

Answer (score 8):

> if enum is not a memory friendly type

Few Java and Android experts agree with the arguments posted by that one Googler regarding enums. See [Jake Wharton](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/638447874515275776), [Bob Lee](https://twitter.com/crazybob/status/636959556539539457), and [Joshua Bloch](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/628663950389841920), for example.

> what is the best alternative for that in the Android environment

The Android SDK mostly uses `int` constants (`static final`).

Comment: Great answer :) because of the references. I also don't agree with that one Googler.

Answer (score 4):

Use Static constants instead if you're having memory constraint.
The following enum will take around 1,112 bytes

```
public static enum Things {
    THING_1,
    THING_2;
};
```

Or you can have two static int which will take 128 bytes.

```
public static int THING_1 = 1;
public static int THING_2 = 2;
```

You have 10x improvement in the dex file size.

On Other end, Enums have its own advantages - readability, usability, type safe code. I would worry about enum only in particular extreme cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally use `public static final` fields.

```
public static final int CONST_1 = 0;
public static final int CONST_2 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are referring to [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Overhead.)

> Enums often require more than twice as much memory as static
>   constants. You should strictly avoid using enums on Android.

It is implied in the statement that one should use **static constants** instead of enums.